# How would a relative href link look that should only change the protocol of the current URL?

Tags: html, http, https, hyperlink, protocols

Assuming I am on

```
http://sub.example.org/path/index.htm
```

How would a

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

line look if all it should do is changing the protocol to https:

```
https://sub.example.org/path/index.htm
```

*without* needing to know the current URL where the page is located (`sub.example.org/path/index.htm`), so being relative?

Example use case: Provide a "Use secure connection (HTTPS/TLS) from now!" link on all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using relative URIs. A relative URI will always start at some point and then change *everything* to the right of that point.

You can calculate the URL using server side code or JavaScript:

```
location = location.toString().replace(/^http:/, "https:");
```